# Performance issue when the number of Edges are large

Tags: r, igraph

I was working on online example, where virus is spread through a graph. The example is sufficient for small graph i.e. small number of edges and nodes. But I tried it on very large graph i.e. 10000 nodes and 20000 edges, but the below function is not sufficient for large graph because its slow.

My question is how can the below function be converted to Vectorized code can be optimized for large graphs?

```
spreadVirus <- function(G,Vinitial,Activation_probability){  

# Precompute all outgoing graph adjacencies

G$AdjList = get.adjlist(G,mode="out")

# Initialize various graph attributes
V(G)$color    = "blue"
E(G)$color    = "black"
V(G)[Vinitial]$color    <- "yellow"

# List to store the incremental graphs (for plotting later)
Glist <- list(G)
count <- 1

# Spread the infection
active <- Vinitial

while(length(active)>0){
new_infected <- NULL
E(G)$color = "black"

for(v in active){
# spread through the daily contacts of vertex v

daily_contacts <- G$AdjList[[v]]

E(G)[v %->% daily_contacts]$color <- "red"

for(v1 in daily_contacts){

if(V(G)[v1]$color == "blue" & new_color=="red") { 

V(G)[v1]$color <- "red"

new_infected <- c(new_infected,v1)

 } 
}
}
# the next active set
#this needed for updating

active <- new_infected

# Add graph to list
# optional dependening on if i want to graph 
count <- count + 1
Glist[[count]] <- G
}
return(Glist)
}
```

My question is how can the below function can be optimized for large graphs?

Thank You
Muna

Comment: "not sufficient" meaning what?  And what are the for-loop limits of which you speak?  I think these details will help explain what you're specifically asking.

Comment: "not sufficient" meaning what?  The for loop is very slow in executing, for example when I ran it on the larger graph it was executing for three days and I did not get any result. I'm by limits I mean R this is not vectorized code. I want to make the above code a vectorized one i.e. fast.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about R's memory management, but I think the main reason behind slowness in case of larger graphs is that in each loop cycle you copy the graph object, allocating a large chunk of memory. These are even not so large graphs: igraph runs happily with graphs of millions of nodes/edges. 
You might consider to keep only one graph object, and create new vertex attributes in each step:

```
spreadVirus <- function(G,Vinitial,Activation_probability){  
    # Precompute all outgoing graph adjacencies
    G$AdjList <- get.adjlist(G, mode = "out")

    # Initialize various graph attributes
    V(G)$step0    <- "blue"
    E(G)$color    <- "black"
    V(G)[Vinitial]$color    <- "yellow"

    # Spread the infection
    active <- Vinitial

    step <- 0
    while(length(active)>0){
        step <- step + 1
        new_infected <- NULL
        E(G)$color <- "black"
        vertex.attributes(g)[[sprintf('step%d', step)]] <- 
        vertex.attributes(g)[[sprintf('step%d', step - 1)]]

        for(v in active){
            # spread through the daily contacts of vertex v

            daily_contacts <- G$AdjList[[v]]

            E(G)[v %->% daily_contacts]$color <- "red"

            for(v1 in daily_contacts){

                vertex.attributes(g)[[sprintf('step%d', step)]][v1] <- "red"
                new_infected <- c(new_infected, v1)

                } 
            }
        }
    # the next active set
    #this needed for updating

    active <- new_infected

    # Add graph to list
    # optional dependening on if i want to graph 
    return(G)
}
```

After, you can refer to the `V(G)$step#` attributes to get the infected nodes at each time point. For plotting, you can pass `vertex.color = V(G)$step#`. You can get the infected part of the graph by `induced.subgraph(G, which(V(G)$step#=='red')`.

You can do similarly with edge color attributes.

Comment: Thanks deeenes, can you give me an example  and what happens to if(V(G)[v1]$color == "blue" & new_color=="red")

Comment: I don't see where you initialize the `new_color` variable, and I don't know why is it necessary. As `v1` is an adjacent vertex of `v`, it's color should be set to `'red'`, because in this step it gets infected. However, if you want to set it infected only if it was healthy, then simply do `if(vertex.attributes(G)[[sprintf("step%d", step-1)]][v1] == 'blue'){vertex.attributes(G)[[sprintf('step%d', step)]][v1] <- "red"}`.